# How to write QUnit tests to test for events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, events, qunit

Using QUnit how would you test for window.scroll event? In code below I'm triggering event but this (as far I understand) is put in event queue. `ok` assertion in next line is executed before event callback is called in. How to test for this sort of events?

```
test("should attach panel once window scrolled down past certain point", function() {

    $(window).scrollTop(1110); // puts event in a queue I believe and next line is executed before this scroll event callback
    ok(LozengesPanel.panel.hasClass("fixed"),"lozenges panel is sticky");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Qunit's async callbacks.

Check this- http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#asynchronous-callbacks